# Newtonsoft Json - OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, json.net

All,

Environment:
ASP.net 2.0, Nhibernate 3.3, Json.net (latest, 6.x)

I am using latest version of Newtonsoft.Json library. When I load an entity using nhibernate (my entities reference other entities and are loaded lazily) I receive either an out of memory exception or stackoverflow exception.

Code for outofmemory exception:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    settings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container.DataItem, settings);
```

Code for stackoverflow exception:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
    settings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container.DataItem, settings);
```

People have these issues but there seems to be no solution. I see responses such a your graph is to large or too deep but my object graph is small,- I just call the code above lots of times (once per each object). I need a fix for this.

Comment: Are you sure that your object graph is small? Are you sure that it doesn't continually traverse from one lazy-loaded collection to another, gradually loading the entire database?

Comment: I am going to confirm this next week,- but briefly looking at it I saw no issue.

Comment: I just verified my object graph, it is not the object itself but the returned proxy that is the cause (See answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using lazy loading so NHibernate hands back proxies here and there and these proxies have references to a `System.Type` object which will have endless loops and also a reference to the session and sessionfactory which will be heavy on its own, check `NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy`.

So either:

- eager load the things to serialize or
- specify directly which properties to serialize or
- don't serialize entities alltogether

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I never looked in detail at the proxy class but that makes sense now.